How to solve the "Cannot find module './jdk' " error in react native?
I installed react-native and completed the required setup.
but when I type " npx react-native init hello"
it gives error as:
Error: Cannot find module './jdk'
I tried jdk version 11 and jdk version 17 expecting one of it will work, but same problem with both jdk version.

This kind of errors come when trying to initialize a new React Native project typically suggests an issue with the environment setup or Node.js modules. Here's a checklist to help troubleshoot and resolve the issue:
Verify Node.js Installation
Ensure you have the latest LTS version of Node.js installed. You can check the version using:
node -v

Clean Cache
Sometimes, issues arise from cached modules or npm cache. Try cleaning the cache:
npm cache clean --force

Reinstall react-native-cli Globally (if needed)
Although using npx doesn’t require a global installation of react-native-cli, reinstalling it might solve the issue:
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native-cli

Reinstall the npx Command
If npx itself is problematic, reinstalling the package might help:
npm install -g npx

Check Your Environment Variables
Ensure that your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set correctly to the JDK path.
For JDK 11 or 17, the path should typically be something like:
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/your/jdk

Add this to your .bashrc, .zshrc, or .bash_profile (depending on your shell) and then run:
source ~/.bashrc

Try a Clean Start
Remove node_modules and run a clean install
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

Use a Specific React Native Version
If the latest version is causing issues, try initializing with a specific version:
npx react-native init hello --version X.XX.X

Replace X.XX.X with a known stable version like 0.71.0.
Ensure Java and Android SDK are Properly Configured
Double-check your Android SDK setup in Android Studio.
Make sure your JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME paths are correctly set and point to valid installations.
Hope above steps will help to solve your problem
